# Controlling how fast a table is written with data from a server sent event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, server-sent-events

I'm writing a table in html with data I receive from a server-sent event.  Here is my Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    var sse = new EventSource('/my_event_source');

    sse.onmessage = function(e) {

      // Build the table
      values = e.data.split("\t");
      var rows_data = [];
      $.each(values, function(index, value) {
        rows_data.push("<td>" + value + "</td>")
      });

      var table_row = "<tr>" + rows_data.join() + "</tr>";
      $("#some_div").append(table_row);

    };
})
```

While the table is written one row at a time, the rows are written really fast!  Any advice on how to slow the writing down?  JavaScript apparently does not have a sleep function, so I have been trying to use setTimeout(), but I am not getting the result I want.  I have tried delay() from jQuery as well, but that is for animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the best solution, but should work:

```
var queue=[];
var interval=setInterval(function(){addRow(), 1000});

function addRow(){
    if(queue.length > 0){
       var row= queue[0];
       queue.shift();
       $("#some_div").append(row);
    }
}

$(document).ready(
function() {
var sse = new EventSource('/my_event_source');

sse.onmessage = function(e) {

  // Build the table
  values = e.data.split("\t");
  var rows_data = [];
  $.each(values, function(index, value) {
    rows_data.push("<td>" + value + "</td>")
  });

  var table_row = "<tr>" + rows_data.join() + "</tr>";
  queue.push(table_row);      


};
```

})

Comment: Awesome.  One small note.  `var interval = setInterval(function(){addRow()}, 1000);`  That is what you want.